# I cannot open a project with linked files wht error "The file could not be added to the project. This file is within the project directory tree error"

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a  MVC web application with my friend. He just sent me a new version of a project. When I rebuilded it, I got warning and the browser opens the old version of a project.

Warning:

> Warning   1   The file '..\ProjectX.Data.CF\DbContextDatabase.cs' could
>   not be added to the project.  Cannot add a link to the file
>   E:\Naloge\ITC\ProjectXService
>   17.6\ProjectX.Data.CF\DbContextDatabase.cs. This file is within the project directory tree.   ProjectX.Data.CF

This is the second time that this happend to me when he sent me new version, and last time I swiched computers because I couldn't fix this (So last time I ended up delleting SQL server and got other issues afterwards).Now I just tried cleaning project, restarting computer and cleaning folders:

- :\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- :\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
- :\ Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCach
- :\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Backup Files.
- :\ Users\\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3
- :\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio\13.0\ProjectAssemblies

Why is still opening my old Project? Project works with no problem if I open it on third computer who didn't had any old versions of a project.

Comment: Where is your csproj and/or sln pointing to?

Comment: Did you check whether the message is correct and the project includes a linked file to a non-existing path? What are the paths of the project file and DbContextDatabase.cs ? "Cleaning" system folders, or reinstalling unrelated applications is a sure way to create a lot of problems and won't help at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The file could not be added to the project. This file is within the project directory tree error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845598/the-file-could-not-be-added-to-the-project-this-file-is-within-the-project-dire)

Comment: Okay I tried renaming the old project if something maybe poiting to the old one and now it works. It opens new project. But warning remains....about the warning I don't know how to get the full path. Its written '..\Project ...?